# Oracle PL/SQL: calling stored procedure with parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have created a stored procedure and compiled it successfully without any errors. However, when I call it within an annoynmous block, it returns an error message `PLS-00201: identifier 'DUE_FOR_RAISE' must be declared`. 
What seems to be wrong? Is there something wrong with the procedure calling? 
This is what I used to call the procedure:
`BEGIN due_for_raise('Austin'); END;`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've quoted your procedure name (never do this). You need to call it with quotes and *exactly* the same casing as you used to name the procedure, so:

```
BEGIN 
   "due_for_raise"('Austin'); 
END;
```

If would be easier to drop your old procedure, and re-create it without a quoted name.

To quote from the documentation on [Database Object Names and Qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#sthref737):

> Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names. These quoted identifiers are accepted by SQL*Plus, but they may not be valid when using other tools that manage database objects.

Comment: I never thought this would matter as APEX adds that automatically to every procedure I create. Anyway, thanks so much!!!